# Read properties file from included jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, module

I am trying to create Annotation parser that reads properties file. The structure looks like this:

```
 - annotationParserModule
    - declaration of interace
    - annotationParser
```

now my app has structurelike this:

```
 - main
   - java
   - resources
      - .properties file
```

I am including annotationParserModule via maven, so if i a not mistaken, jar fire is inlcuded in my project.

However i need to read properties file outside of the jar provided by `annotationParserModule`, is somethig like that possible? If so, what is the right way to achieve this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

If the resource you want to read are included in the classpath of your application (eg. inside a jar, in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder, a folder passed with `-cp` to `java` command, etc..) you can read the file using the [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) method of the `Class` class.

Providing an example for your case, having folders like:

```
- main
   - java
   - resources
      - yourconfig.properties
```

In your `YourAnnotationParser` code you can have:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("yourconfig.properties");
```

If the file is nested:

```
- main
   - java
   - resources
      - iamafolder
          - yourconfig.properties
```

So:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("iamafolder/yourconfig.properties");
```

BTW this is a very simplistic response, the code works on common scenario, what it does behind the scenes is more complex than "read a file outside a jar", but to understand it fully you need to look for how the java class loader and the classpath work.

If the file is outside the java classpath you can use the `File` class or the `URL` one to read contents.

Comment: My project does not have WEB-INF/lib folder,  or did u mean i just have to keep it inside resource package? I am using spring-boot. Using this inside my processor threw nullpointer exception:
InputStream words = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(name + ".properties"); PropertyResourceBundle bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(new InputStreamReader(words));

Comment: also using FIle i would have to put absolute path , no?

Comment: using `File` you can also use a relative path, but is very discouraged as it is relative from the path in which the `java` command is executed...
For the `getResourceAsStream` it should be ok, the `resource` folder is part of the classpath.
BTW spring boot does some magic trick when it package the artifact, can you try to use the same piece of code in the same project where the `properties` file is located to check it works?

Comment: ah, its also null there, weird

Comment: mmm can you try naming it with a `/` at the beginning like: `/yourconfig.properties`

Comment: i have used this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name + ".properties"); and it has started to work :)

Answer (score 0):

In you applicationcontext.xml you can add the bean to read the properties file from the jar

```
<bean id="com.mybean"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/resource.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and this id will be a reference to another bean

```
<bean id="com.mybean1">
    class="com.dependent.jar.classname">
    <property name="properties" ref="com.mybean" />
</bean>
```